# Why typeof is called operator instead of function?

Tags: javascript, operators

While reading this article ([Special Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special_Operators)) in MDC, I got a question like why  `typeof, new,` etc. are called operators?

I have a conception say `+` is a operator because it operators on two entities like `2+3` and gives another value.

Ofcourse functions also operates on say two entities like the same way.

Then what is difference?

Thanks for any answers.

Comment: @Yi Jiang modified. no more angry :-)

Answer (score 2):

No, being an operator isn't about whether or not it's got two operands - that's the difference between a *unary* operator and a *binary* operator (and then there's the conditional operator with three operands, which is an example of a *ternary* operator). For example, + can also be a unary operator:

```
var x = +5;
```

You can sort of thing of operators as "built-in functions". They're known about by the JavaScript engine itself, and are part of the *language* rather than just being *library* features. (Although operators can often be overloaded by libraries, depending on the language. I don't know if JavaScript supports operator overloading, offhand.)

In some cases (JavaScript being an example) there's a bit of a blurring between the language and the standard library, but think about what `typeof` takes as an operand: it's the name of a type. That's not something you can use normally as a function argument; it needs special support in the language.

Comment: The operand of `typeof` in JavaScript is any object or primitive, not specifically the name of a type. And no, JavaScript doesn't support operator overloading.

Comment: Jon, do you do JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

`++` is also an operator with only one argument.

One of the differences is that you don't call an operator with parameters, i.e you write `typeof a` or `new SomeObject()`, whereas a function `type_of` would be called with `type_of(a)`. But like Jon said, you can kind of think of them as built-in functions. As a side note `()` in `myFunc(arg1, arg2)` is a function-application operator, i.e it invokes a function with the arguments given.

Comment: () is a "function call" operator.

Comment: if you "call a function with arguments" or "apply a function to arguments" is just a matter of phrasing. but sure, given the `function.call()` method available in javascript, maybe your wording is preferred...